# Generate token for scope works without defining API permission?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-ad-msal

I created an app registration in Azure that has only one API permission:

[image: app registration permissions]

In my code, I am creating an access token to access the log analytics API. The resource parameter in the code refers to https://api.loganalytics.io/.default. Surprisingly, this access token allows me to read my log analytics workspace, even though I never defined the log analytic API permission on the app registration.

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = _confidentialClientFactory.Create(clientId, clientSecret, resource, authority);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

However, I came across a page that stated I needed to add the log analytic API as a permission in API permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/access-api This is confusing because my code is working without explicitly adding the log analytic API permission to my app registration.

Does anyone know how this is working?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application and API permissions** looks like this:

[image]

I generated **access token** via Client Credentials by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://api.loganalytics.io/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token the **aud** is `https://api.loganalytics.io` :

[image]

I tried to execute the query and got the **error** like below:

```json
POST https://api.loganalytics.azure.com/v1/workspaces/DEMO_WORKSPACE/query
    X-Api-Key: DEMO_KEY
    Content-Type: application/json
    
    {
        "query": "AzureActivity | summarize count() by Category"
    }
```

[image]

> **Note** that: To access log analytic API, it is necessary to add the API permission. Without necessary permissions it's not possible to access log analytics.

If you are able to access log analytics without explicitly adding the log analytic API permission to app registration, check below:

- *Go to Subscriptions -> Access control (IAM) -> Role Assignments -> and check the roles the app registration is assigned*

[image]

The Application might have been assigned role to access Log analytics.

- Check if the API permission is under **`Other permissions granted for Directory`** like below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, create a new Azure AD Application and generate access token and check.

After granting required **API permission** I am able to access Log analytics successfully like below:

[image]

Try using scope as `https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io/.default` and generate access token. When I decoded the token **aud** is `https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io` :

[image]

[image]